# Tomar en cuenta las comillas con Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

estoy intentando limpiar un csv y que mediante por regex entienda que tiene que realizar un salto de linea luego del campo "email", debo hacerlo en python 2.7
Por ejemplo, en la fila 29 tengo los valores de esa fila separados en varias, necesitaria lograr que los datos de Adena Hobbs queden todos en la misma fila, lo mismo me pasa en varias filas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice lo siguiente:

```
regex4 = '[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
regex3 = '[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
regex = '[a-zA-Z]+[\._]?[a-zA-Z]+[\._]?[a-zA-Z]+[@][a-zA-Z]+[.]\w{2,3}$'
regex2 = '[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'


for index, value in enumerate(x):
    
    if (re.search(regex4,value, re.I)):
      x[index] = value + '\n'
    
    elif (re.search(regex3,value, re.I)):
      x[index] = value + '\n'
    
    elif (re.search(regex,value, re.I)):
      x[index] = value + '\n'
    
    elif (re.search(regex2,value, re.I)):
      x[index] = value + '\n'
```

y luego escribi fila por fila, logré juntar todos los datos en la misma fila pero me está obviando la ultima comilla doble del campo email, lo que me provoca que todo se escriba en columnas en vez de en filas, muestro imagen a continuación:
[image: Csv final]

Comment: La cantidad de espacios entre cada campo es 2?

Comment: Solo están separados por la ,

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con la primera imagen, cada persona tiene 5 campos, los que siempre están presentes (ni uno más, ni uno menos).

En tal caso puedo usar un esquema mucho más simple y directo: leer el archivo como una larga lista de elementos y agruparlos de a cinco.

```
with open("test.data", "r") as data:
    registro = []
    for linea in data.readlines():
        registro.extend(linea.split())
        if len(registro) >= 5:
            print(','.join(registro[:5]))
            del registro[:5]
```

Leemos el archivo línea a línea y usamos `split()` para dividirla en sus partes. Esto tiene el beneficio adicional de eliminar los espacios.

Luego agregamos las partes a `registro`. Como `split()` retorna una lísta, se `extend` para agregar todos sus elementos (no `append`, que agregaria la lista como un solo elemento).

Si `registro` tiene 5 o más elementos, tomamos los cinco primeros y generamos una línea de salida en formato CSV usando `join()`.

Finalmente eliminamos los cinco elementos ya impresos. No limpiamos la lista, ya que la línea leida puede traer elementos adicionales, los que se procesan en la siguiente vuelta.

#### Demo

*test.data*

```
id first_name second_name account_number email
1 
Jacinta Lopez
99032 jacinta@hotmail.com
2 Roberto Perez 99034 perez@perez.com

3

Jaime

Pavez

99035

pavez@roma.com 4 Rolando Soto 99040 roli@rolox.com
```

produce:

```
id,first_name,second_name,account_number,email
1,Jacinta,Lopez,99032,jacinta@hotmail.com
2,Roberto,Perez,99034,perez@perez.com
3,Jaime,Pavez,99035,pavez@roma.com
4,Rolando,Soto,99040,roli@rolox.com

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: El problema es que no está teniendo en cuenta los campos con apellido compuesto como el de Adena Hoobs que muestro en la linea 29. Por lo cual a partir de ese campo comienza a desordenarse y pone el mail como 1er campo.